# SSRS SubReport Issue

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a reporting service project.
All of the reports are saved with a .rdl extension.
I have one report that has several sub reports.
The report runs perfectly in visual studio.
The reports are deployed {copied to a file server}
When I run, the deployed report I encountered an error saying that the report can not find my sub report for example {MySubReport.rdlc}

Notice the .rdlc extension.

I am not sure why the run time engine is looking for a .rdlc when all I can deploy are .rdl's from my report project.

Thanks
Gerry

Comment: Is the report working at your PC.

Comment: Yes the report works perfectly when I run it through Visual Studio on my PC.

Comment: How about the report run time on server part?

Comment: That is the problem, when the report runs on the server it looks for a .rdlc file and all I can provide is a .rdl file as a subreport.

Comment: Is it the error retuns? .rdlc file?

Comment: The problem is, when the report loads off the server it expects a .rdlc file.  Reporting service error is something like can not locate MySubReport.rdlc, there exists a MySubReport.rdl and this sub report works great within the Visual Studio environment.

Comment: All the reports in my project have a .rdl extension.  I tried to rename the .rdl to .rdlc and of course this did not work.

Comment: `The reports are deployed {copied to a file server}`. Are they actually deployed (published) or do you manual copy them? Also, what version of VS and SSRS are you running? The `.rdlc` extension is for the `Report Viewer Control`.

Comment: Report rdl's are copied to a file server.  I am running VS2012 and we are viewing reports in a Report Viewer Control.  I think SSRS is 2010